# getElementById from range

Tags: vba, excel

I scrape an internal admin system with over 100 text fields using IE into excel. The below code finds the column "productType" and places the "productType" value into the actve row in the correct column.

```
lngCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("productType", Worksheets("Data").Range("1:1"), 0)
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, lngCol).Cells(1, 1).Value = IE.document.getElementById("productType").Value
```

The code is getting too long as I am copying/pasting the above code for every individual element, whereas I'd like to have a range of the Id's that I want to extract, and have one line of code that loops through the range.

However, when running the below I am getting an object required error on the last row?

```
myDivID = "productType"

lngCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(myDivID, Worksheets("Data").Range("1:1"), 0)
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, lngCol).Cells(1, 1).Value = IE.document.getElementById(myDivID).Value
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you please share a sample of your data including the problem part?

Comment: ...and you get an error "on the last line *of code*" or "on the last line *of data*"?  Either way, start by adding this line to the very top of the module `Option Explicit`, and then try running it.  It will force you to declare variables, objects, etc., and often quickly locates a mistake.

Comment: ...and where is this range of ID's? On a worksheet?